# Monitor and switch multiple clients connections in c

Tags: c, sockets, select, server, network-programming

I am implementing a Linux C program for client/server. I am using `select()` to connect with multiple clients. The 1st client connected successfully, but 2nd, 3rd and so on, have not give response any response in terminal(server), although client program is executed. The server is connected with some custom shell that run on client side.My server code is:

```
 /**Handle multiple socket connections with select and fd_set on Linux*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>   
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>   
#include <arpa/inet.h>    
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/time.h> 
#include <pthread.h>
 
#define TRUE   1
#define FALSE  0
#define PORT 80
#define BUFSIZE 1025


void *sending( void *fdc)
//void sending(int fd_client)
{
    int fd_client= *((int *)fdc);
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    while(1)
    {
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        fgets(buffer,512,stdin);
        
        if((write(fd_client,buffer,strlen(buffer)))==0)
            {
                printf("HOST [%d] DISCONNECTED \n",fd_client);
                close(fd_client);
            }
            if((!strcmp(buffer,"quit")) || (!strcmp(buffer,"q")) || (!strcmp(buffer,"QUIT")) || (!strcmp(buffer,"Q")))
            {
                exit(1);
            }

    }
}
void *receiving( void *arg)
//void receiving(int fd_client)
{
    int fd_client= *((int *)arg);
    char buffer[BUFSIZE];
    ssize_t size;
    while(1)
    {
       do{
            if((size=read(fd_client,buffer,BUFSIZE))==0)
            {
                printf("HOST [%d] DISCONNECTED \n",fd_client);
                close(fd_client);
            }
            if((write(1,buffer,size))==-1)
            {
                printf("Eror in Writting to client\n");
                perror("");
                exit(0);
            }
        }while(size==BUFSIZE);

    }
}

//void *socket_thread(void *arg)
void socket_thread(int fd_client)
{
    pthread_t th1,th2;
    
    pthread_create(&th1,NULL,&sending,&fd_client);
    pthread_create(&th2,NULL,&receiving,&fd_client);
    pthread_join(th1,NULL);
    pthread_cancel(th2);
}
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    int opt = TRUE;
    int master_socket , addrlen , new_socket , client_socket[30] , max_clients = 30 , activity, i , valread , sd;
    int max_sd;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
     
    char buffer[1025];  //data buffer of 1K
     
    //set of socket descriptors
    fd_set readfds;
     
    //a message
    char *message = "ECHO Daemon v1.0 \r\n";
 
    //initialise all client_socket[] to 0 so not checked
    for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
    {
        client_socket[i] = 0;
    }
     
    //create a master socket
    if( (master_socket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM , 0)) == 0) 
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    //set master socket to allow multiple connections , this is just a good habit, it will work without this
    if( setsockopt(master_socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, (char *)&opt, sizeof(opt)) < 0 )
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
 
    //type of socket created
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
     
    //bind the socket to localhost port 8888
    if (bind(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address))<0) 
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Listener on port %d \n", PORT);
    
    //try to specify maximum of 3 pending connections for the master socket
    if (listen(master_socket, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
     
    //accept the incoming connection
    addrlen = sizeof(address);
    puts("Waiting for connections ...");
    pthread_t tid[30];
    while(TRUE) 
    {
        //clear the socket set
        FD_ZERO(&readfds);
 
        //add master socket to set
        FD_SET(master_socket, &readfds);
        max_sd = master_socket;
        
        //add child sockets to set
        for ( i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
        {
            //socket descriptor
            sd = client_socket[i];
            
            //if valid socket descriptor then add to read list
            if(sd > 0)
                FD_SET( sd , &readfds);
            
            //highest file descriptor number, need it for the select function
            if(sd > max_sd)
                max_sd = sd;
        }
 
        //wait for an activity on one of the sockets , timeout is NULL , so wait indefinitely
        activity = select( max_sd + 1 , &readfds , NULL , NULL , NULL);
   
        if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) 
        {
            printf("select error");
        }
         
        //If something happened on the master socket , then its an incoming connection
        if (FD_ISSET(master_socket, &readfds)) 
        {
            if ((new_socket = accept(master_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
            {
                perror("accept");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            //inform user of socket number - used in send and receive commands
            printf("New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" , new_socket , inet_ntoa(address.sin_addr) , ntohs(address.sin_port));
       
            puts("Welcome message sent successfully");
             
            for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
            {
                //if position is empty
                if( client_socket[i] == 0 )
                {
                    client_socket[i] = new_socket;
                    printf("Adding to list of sockets as %d\n" , i);
                    
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
         
        //else its some IO operation on some other socket :)
        for (i = 0; i < max_clients; i++) 
        {
            sd = client_socket[i];
            if (FD_ISSET( sd , &readfds)) 
            {
               socket_thread(sd);
               
            }
        }
    } 
     
    return 0;
}
```

The program work perfectly for one client but not for multiple. I also tries multi-threads for each file descriptor  instead of using select(), but in this case the 2nd client connection overtake the first one in terminal. I want the following outcomes:

1. Switch between multiple connected clients from Linux terminal(i,e by pressing some keys from keyboard).
2. When new client is connected in-between, , it prompt a signal , and also can be switch to further read and write operations.
   Any help regrading this will be appreciated.

Comment: You are reading from `stdin` from multiple threads. How is that supposed to work out? It seems you are left with code from trying out different strategies. You need to first decide on a strategy. I would suggest dropping the multi-threaded approach for now.

Comment: `if ((activity < 0) && (errno!=EINTR)) ` On EINTR you should `continue;`, not falltru (the FD_SETs are in an undefined state)

Comment: `}while(size==BUFSIZE);` <<-- do you know how wrong this is?

Comment: Why are you spawning threads to send and receive for each client? When using `select()`, you don't need to use any threads *at all*. `select()` will tell you when a client has data waiting to be read, just read it immediately and then process/buffer it as needed. For sending, allocate a buffer for each client, and if `send()` reports `EWOULDBLOCK` then put the remaining+subsequent data in that buffer, and let `select()` tell you when you can `send()` that buffer, removing whatever is successful. Don't `send()` new data until the buffer is emptied, put it at the end of the buffer instead.